# Android LazyAdapter for ListView

Tags: android, android-lazyadapter

I think I messed up with my Context. Could somebody correct my codes? I cant seems to figure out how to implement Context into my lazyadapter. please take a look at my LOGCAT. Thanks.

AndroidFragment.java

```
public class AndroidFragment extends SherlockListFragment  implements ActionBar.TabListener{

    static final String URL = "https://myxml.xml";
    static final String KEY_SONG = "song";
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_CAT_ARTIST = "artistcat";
    static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";
    static final String KEY_CAT_URL = "cat_url";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems;
    ListAdapter adapter;
    Context appContext;
    ListView list;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        appContext = inflater.getContext().getApplicationContext();

        new loadListView().execute();   

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }


    public class loadListView extends AsyncTask<Integer, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Integer... args) {
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
            // looping through all item nodes <item>
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                map.put(KEY_CAT_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_CAT_ARTIST));
                map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
                map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));
                map.put(KEY_CAT_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_CAT_URL));

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                menuItems.add(map);
            }
                return null;
            }   


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String args) {


            adapter=new MainPageLazyAdapter(appContext, menuItems);   
             list.setAdapter(adapter);
         }
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, this);

        ft.attach(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.detach(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

MainPageLazyAdapter.java

```
public class MainPageLazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Application activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public MainPageImageLoader imageLoader; 

public MainPageLazyAdapter(Context appContext, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = appContext;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new MainPageImageLoader(activity);
}
```

I got this error :

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Context to Application
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `(Activity)` cast you use in the constructor. You already used `inflator.getContext.getApplicationContext` when you created an instance and you cannot cast it to an `Activity` context again. Either you pass the `inflator.getContext()` only (if you use the `Activity` context, you may get a memory leak), or you use the `Application` context, so you remove the `Activity` cast.

**Edit:**

You already have the ApplicationContext passed to the constructor, so there is no need to cast it again to Activity:

```
activity = (Activity) appContext;
```

Then get the Application context again:

```
imageLoader=new MainPageImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
```

Just set `activity = appContext;` (the variable should be named Application now) and pass it directly `imageLoader=new MainPageImageLoader(activity);`

Comment: thanks but I dont understand what you mean by "or you use the Application context, so you remove the Activity cast"

Comment: The getActivity() will return null if the fragment is not attached.onCreateView.

Comment: Please check. I got this error when I changed the variable to Application "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Context to Application"

Comment: No, I just meant the naming not the type. Sorry if you misunderstood me. Keep activity as Context type (it refers to an Application context not an Application)

Answer (score 1):

look to `MainPageLazyAdapter` constructor code: `activity = (Activity) appContext;`

from other hand - class `AndroidFragment.onCreateView`: 
    appContext = inflater.getContext().getApplicationContext();

and in `AndroidFragment.onPostExecute` : 

`adapter=new MainPageLazyAdapter(appContext, menuItems);`

so - you are casting Application Context to Activity and it сouses cast error.

to avoid this situation you might override `AndroidFragment.onAttach` method and add one member to `AndroidFragment`:

```
protected Activity fragmentActivity;    
@Override public void onAttach (Activity activity){
    fragmentActivity = activity;
}
```

then replace 
`adapter=new MainPageLazyAdapter(appContext, menuItems);` 
with 
 `adapter=new MainPageLazyAdapter(fragmentActivity, menuItems);`

and ... consider move `imageLoader=new MainPageImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());` 
to `onAttach()`